# Convert double br tags to p tags in tinymce 4

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce-4

What I want to do is to convert double br to p in tinymce 4 this is what I put in my tinymce config

```
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block: false,

        language : 'fr_FR',
        setup : function(ed) {

                ed.on('onPostProcess', function(ed, o) {
                    o.content = o.content.replace(/<br\s?\/?><br\s?\/?>/gi, '</p><p>');
                });
```

but nothing happen , I don't know want I want is possible in tinymce 4
for example if I have :

```
This is a test 1<br /><br />
This is a test 2<br /><br />
This is a test 3<br /><br />
This is a test 4<br /><br />
```

It convert automatically in :

```
<p>This is a test 1</p>
<p>This is a test 2</p>
<p>This is a test 3</p>
<p>This is a test 4</p>
```

Comment: Is text on single line or multiine text too ?? Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/OqEikD/2/) ?

Comment: Use `(<br[^>]*>){2,}`

Comment: You are specifically configuring TinyMCE to use BR tags and not P tags in your configuration yet you want P tags in the output?  If you want P tags and not BR tags why set those 3 "force" configuration options at all?

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from [*Regular Expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) when working with the DOM. Use the Node API to alter the document.

You can check if the next two siblings are breaks and wrap the text content 
with a paragraph, and at the same time — remove the breaks.

```js
replaceDoubleBreaks(document.getElementById('content'));

function replaceDoubleBreaks(target) {
  var children = target.childNodes;
  if (children.length > 0) {
    var currIndex = 0, currNode = children[currIndex];
    while (currNode != null) {
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType
      if (currNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        if (isBreak(currNode.nextSibling) && isBreak(currNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)) {
          var p = document.createElement('p');
          p.innerHTML = currNode.textContent.trim();
          currNode.replaceWith(p);
          for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) target.removeChild(children[currIndex + 1]);
        }
      }
      currIndex++;
      currNode = children[currIndex];
    }
  }
}

function isBreak(el) {
  return el && el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'br';
}
```

```css
p { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<div id="content">
This is a test 1<br /><br />
This is a test 2<br /><br />
This is a test 3<br /><br />
This is a test 4<br /><br />
</div>
```

Here is an example using TinyMCE

> https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/sucLumb2/

Comment: thanks for helping me , but this is not what I want . I want to reproduce the same behaviour of wordpress , when you press twice the key 'enter' it convert automatically in <p> markup